# iPhone Simulator Icon Black

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, ios-simulator

I have two Icon files in my plist:
icon.png
icon@2x.png

Both are added to my project, added to the target and are
57x57 and 114x114 pixels respectively, both 72 dpi.

They are both pngs generated from a .svg.

I filled out the transparency with white. The rest of the coloring is black.

I have tried deleting the app, clearing derived data and re-running.

Why is this icon showing a black square in the iPhone 6 simulator?

EDIT: Tried renaming to capital I in Icon.png and Icon@2x.png. Wiped app, wiped derived data, clean, still no dice.

Comment: The iPhone 6 simulator doesn't support icons, because the iPhone 6 doesn't exist.

Comment: I believe that refers to iOS6 on iPhone, not "iPhone 6"

Comment: Ended up making a new icon in Photoshop. @pedro gave a good answer though so I marked as correct.

Comment: The "i" in icon should be capital.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle , you are correct. That still didn't fix the issue though, it was something with exporting from Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1 - On the simulator remove your app just like you delete an app on an iPhone.

2 - On xcode go to the menu Product and click Clean. (Or the shortcut Shift+Command+K)

3 - Try to run again.

edit: When you open the png's on your computer do they actually show the white?

Comment: In Photoshop I see the white. In Preview it shows a grey background like the rest of the Preview box

Comment: Try with a random icon to find if the problem is with xcode or with the png's

Comment: Made one fresh in Photoshop. You gave a good answer so marking as correct.

Answer (score 4):

So I was having the same problem and found this old thread.  In my case the issue turned out to be the alpha channel in the PNG icon.  Specifically: my icon was black-on-transparent, so on the simulator with a black background it showed as black-on-black.  I solved by opening in Preview and exporting with the "alpha" button turned off.