# AppStore icon becomes Full black

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, xcode10.1

App binary rejected and message is as following

**Guideline 2.3.8 - Performance - Accurate Metadata**

**We noticed the app icon displayed on the device and the large icon displayed on the App Store do not sufficiently match, which makes it difficult for users to find the app they just downloaded.**

**Next Steps**

**To resolve this issue, please ensure all your app icons are finalized and similar enough to each other to avoid creating confusion. When users search for your app on their devices, they should be able to recognize it from the icon on the App Store.**

1.When I click **Choose File** the app-icon shows perfectly

thereafter selecting a build, it again changed to fully black coloured icon

**EDIT** Note: I tried without choosing icon manually in iTunes connect, added 1024 image in assets is Automatically selected and shown as App Store large icon, again icon becomes full black.

[image: AppStore icon after selecting a build]

[image: AppStore icon before selecting a build]

Comment: Does your icon have a white background or a transparent background ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858501/ios-app-icon-with-transparent-background-showing-black-background-on-device

Comment: No,transparent binaries will get rejected by xcode itself while uploading

Comment: Then it is probably this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242759/iphone-simulator-icon-black There is still an alpha channel behind. Open the icon in Preview and export it without the alpha channel

Comment: @Anees can you show me your icon in Xcode project ? you have to put same logo in Xcode Project --> Assets.xcassets --> AppIcon --> 1024pt

Comment: @NiravKotecha just click and drag image i uploaded above it will shows the icon border in mild grey colour. then you'll realise the bug. It is not because of wrong image, some kind of bug from appstoreconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, Just delete AppIcon from Appstoreconnect webpage, It will automatically accepts 1024 image added in Appicon file in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
AppStore Webpage, Appstore Apps and TestFlight Logo is full black.

Contacted Apple Support, They suggested the following steps.

1. Sign out of App Store Connect
2. Clear your web browser history
3. Quit the web browser
4. Restart the web browser
5. Sign back in and submit a new build with the updated icon and re-submit the app for review.

The issue is not fixed even after following the above steps.

I deleted app icons in the project and added a new set of icons. And uploaded. This issue is fixed